# Azure Devops REST API - Using PAT - return redirect Object moved

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm having problems authenticating Azure Devops API using console applications

After call Get Projects API on AzureDevOps i get a redirect... to login page

```
curl -u :${B64_PAT} "https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"
```

Return:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://spsprodsbr1.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?rea
```

I need call this API from a "Java Server Application", but I'm having a problem with this return to the login page. But I would like to follow Device Authentication flow

Answer (score 7):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, to solve the issue, please pass your PAT directly to the command without base64 encode.

```
curl -u :<PAT> "https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"
```

[image]

Comment: I can't believe it was just that. I ended up implementing oauth, I'm going to use PAT because it's really simpler... Thanks.